# PHP- Isset() function, checkin parameters

Tags: php, isset

I need help figuring out correct PHP coding for isset function.

I am having problems understanding exactly what I need to do with the `isset()` function. Below I have the assignment directions, I have completed up to the end of *part b*, using the `isset()` function to check that the parameters exists in the query string. When I built the form, the form action is *"GET"*, because it needs to be in the query string, is that also correct?

My only two variables are `Value1` and `Value2`, which are input by the user.

**SimpleCalculator.php** - Write a script that retrieves two values from the querystring, adds them together and displays the results.

Steps:

> 1. Copy the code from HelloForm.php and modify it to display two text boxes. Assign the values entered to variables named `value1` and `value2`.
> 2. In your PHP code assign the parameters from the querystring to local variables named `$value1` and `$value2`. You will need to use the `isset()` function to check that the two parameters are in the querystring.
> 3. Echo the variables to the browser to make sure they have been retrieved correctly.
> 4. Add and print the values with the statement:
>
>    echo 'Sum is: ' . ($Value1 + $Value2);

This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample web form</title>
        <link href="/sandvig/mis314/assignments/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

<body>
<div class="pageContainer centerText">

<h2>Simple Calculations </h2>
<hr />

<form method="get" >
    Please enter two numbers:<br><br>
    Value 1: <input type="text" name="Value1" autofocus> <br><br>
    Value 2: <input type="text" name="Value2" autofocus> <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
 </form>

 <?php

 $value1 = $_GET ['Value1'];
 $value2 = $_GET ['Value2'];

 //Retrieve name from querystring. Check that parameter
 //is in querystring or may get "Undefined index" error

 echo 'Value 1 was:' . ($value1);
 echo 'Value 2 was:' . ($value2);
 echo 'Sum is: ' . ($value1 + $Value2);

 ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, check [this manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) about `isset()` function.

How it works?

```
$value1 = isset($_GET ['Value1']) ? $_GET ['Value1'] : null;
$value2 = isset($_GET ['Value2']) ? $_GET ['Value2'] : null;
```

Now, if user send something as `Value1` parameter in query-string, so `$value1` variable will be assigned with that data; if no `null` will be assigned. Same for `value2`.

Simple :)

Answer (score 0):

It does not say what to do if the value is not set, however this is the best way to get the values. You could display an error if $value1 or $value2 is not set. In the example below, they will be null.

```
$value1 = isset($_GET['Value1']) ? $_GET['Value1'] : null;
$value2 = isset($_GET['Value2']) ? $_GET['Value2'] : null;
```

http://www.php.net/isset

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET))
{
    $value1 = isset($_GET ['Value1']) ? $_GET ['Value1'] : null;
    $value2 = isset($_GET ['Value2']) ? $_GET ['Value2'] : null;

   //Retrieve name from querystring. Check that parameter
   //is in querystring or may get "Undefined index" error

   echo 'Value 1 was:' . ($value1);
   echo 'Value 2 was:' . ($value2);
   echo 'Sum is: ' . ($value1 + $Value2);
}
?>
```

Comment: If `$value1` and `$value2` are empty, you're making a bad sum:  `""+""`. duh?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example of my get() function:

```
<?php

$arr = [];

var_dump( get($arr,'a','b') ); // NULL

$arr['a']['b'] = 'ab';
var_dump( get($arr,'a','b') ); // 'ab'

//var_dump(get($arr,'aa'));

/*
    Get with safety
    @author: boctulus

    @param array 
    @param index1
    @param index2
    ..
*/
function get(){ 
    $numargs  = func_num_args();
    $arg_list = func_get_args();

    $v = $arg_list[0];  

    for ($i = 1; $i < $numargs; $i++) 
    {
            if (isset($v[$arg_list[$i]]))
            $v = $v[$arg_list[$i]];
        else
            return null;
    }

    return $v;
}
```

You see ? you can get without any risk :)